# AJAX request doesn't go to readystate 4

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to use AJAX for the first time and I've encountered an issue. I didn't manage to resolve it by reading tutorials.

I have a PHP file on my server which echoes the correct output when I access the file directly. However when I try accessing it through a HTML. Here is my javascript code:

```
        var httpRequest;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
            httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 8 and older
            httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        httpRequest.open('GET', 'http://www.mysite.com/myfile.php?variable1=' + variable1 + "&variable2=" + variable2, true);
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
                var receivedString = httpRequest.responseText;
                console.log(receivedString);
            } else {
                console.log(httpRequest.readyState);
            }
        };
```

nothing happens; neither receivedString nor the value of httpRequest.readyState is output. What could be the reason?

Comment: do you see any problems in your console?

Comment: no, no errors in chrome console

Comment: Where do you call .send() on your request object?

Comment: You forgot to call `httpRequest.send()`

Comment: @kinakuta I don't. This may be the problem. Where should I call it?

Comment: Add that to the end of the code you've shown us.

Comment: Your plain, to-the-point comments have been helpful, it works now. I will accept the best formulated answer once the stack exchange timer lets me. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append `httpRequest.send(null);` to your code.

The request is not sent to the server until the `send` method is called, so the `readyState` property does not change and the `onreadystatechange` event is not fired.